# How to convert a string of a tuple into a list in python?

Tags: python, string, list, file

So the title sounds odd because perhaps my problem is odd... I have a .txt file with thousands of lines of machine output from a different program in the following format:

```
candidates(6,1,0,5,[ev(-1000,'C0009814','Stenosis','Acquired stenosis',[stenosis],[patf])])
```

Essentially we have 'candidates' marking the start of a tuple, and 'ev' marking the start of a second tuple inside of a single element list. When I read all of this into python from the file, it reads in as a string. But I need an object so I can access the nth index of the tuple. Truly, I would be happy just finding a way to consistently get the last value of the ev() tuple from this string, in this case 'patf'.

I had considered just splitting on ',' but this is not always successful because the list inside the list '[stenosis]', can sometimes have values like '[regurgitation, aortic]'. That extra ',' throws off the list index by 1 and therefore it return 'aortic]' instead of '[patf]'.

Please let me know if I can clarify anything or if I took some piece of knowledge for granted that needs to be said before this can be solved. Many thanks. I also included a second examples below that illustrates the problem of splitting on ','.

```
candidates(8,1,0,7,[ev(-875,'C0003501','Aortic Valve','Aortic valve structure',[aortic,valve],[bpoc])])
```

Edit: The object doesn't need to be a list, I guess. A tuple of the same format works well. Just as long as I can consistently reference one index for the info I need. Thanks!

Edit 2: I use python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1):

You have a nested grammar that you're trying to parse.  Albeit it is narrowly scoped, so regex *could* be constructed to deal with it, but it's going to be fragile.  Like, *really* fragile.

Try using `ast`.  This gets a little complex so I'll try to walk (haha) through an an example.  If you want the tl;dr, skip to the middle/end.

We're looking for a name in a list node, so we can start there.

```
import ast

s = "candidates(6,1,0,5,[ev(-1000,'C0009814','Stenosis','Acquired stenosis',[stenosis],[patf])])"

mod = ast.parse(s)

for node in ast.walk(mod):
    if isinstance(node, ast.List):
        print(node, list(ast.iter_child_nodes(node)))

<_ast.List object at 0xb3f2ddec> [<_ast.Call object at 0xb3f2de0c>, <_ast.Load object at 0xb712756c>]
<_ast.List object at 0xb3f2deec> [<_ast.Name object at 0xb3f2df0c>, <_ast.Load object at 0xb712756c>]
<_ast.List object at 0xb3f2df2c> [<_ast.Name object at 0xb3f2df4c>, <_ast.Load object at 0xb712756c>]
```

We see that there are three `ast.List` nodes in our syntax tree.  The first one is going to be the outer list that calls `ev`, and the two inner ones are going to contain those bare `ast.Name` nodes.  That's what we want to get at - you specifically want the second one.

---

**tl;dr skips here**

We can make this all a lot more straightforward, I'm just walking through how I personally explored this syntax tree.  Here's a one-ish-liner:

```
s = "candidates(6,1,0,5,[ev(-1000,'C0009814','Stenosis','Acquired stenosis',[stenosis],[patf])])"

mod = ast.parse(s)

[next(ast.iter_fields(node)) for node in ast.walk(mod) if isinstance(node, ast.Name)]
Out[62]: [('id', 'candidates'), ('id', 'ev'), ('id', 'stenosis'), ('id', 'patf')]
```

So just grab the second index of the last element of that, there's your string.  This approach works for your other example too:

```
s = "candidates(8,1,0,7,[ev(-875,'C0003501','Aortic Valve','Aortic valve structure',[aortic,valve],[bpoc])])"

mod = ast.parse(s)

[next(ast.iter_fields(node)) for node in ast.walk(mod) if isinstance(node, ast.Name)]
Out[65]: 
[('id', 'candidates'),
 ('id', 'ev'),
 ('id', 'aortic'),
 ('id', 'valve'),
 ('id', 'bpoc')]
```

You can use this approach to grab really *any* element you want out of that syntax tree.  Just explore the output of `ast.walk` with `ast.iter_fields` and `ast.iter_child_nodes`.

Comment: This looks very promising! I will start to apply it to some examples and see how well it works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always formatted the same way, the quickest way is to use regular expressions (module `re`), if you know how to.

Otherwise, and this is quite an unsightly hack, you can try to "parse" the data using `eval`. Here's an example:

```
eval_globals = {
    "candidates": lambda *args: args,
    "ev": lambda *args: args,
    "aortic": "aortic",
    "valve": "valve",
    "bpoc": "bpoc",
    # Add more of the keywords you need here
}
result = eval(line, eval_globals)
```

Comment: I will look into eval() and see how robust it is for all situations. Thanks!

Comment: Be aware that this is quite a hack and a severe security hole if someone can influence your logged data. You are executing said data as Python code. It is exactly not a robust solution. Learn about regexes, it will pay off!

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I do know regex, but was hoping that there would be some sort of module that could intelligently interpret a string if it matched an object's format. Again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just split on [. So you can do s.split('[')[-1].split(']')[0] where s is a line from the file ...